# Unknown apps taking over tablet

Tags: hardware

My son's tablet is suddenly over run with apps we don't know about trying to gain information (such as location, password, permission to load). Not sure what he downloaded or did to start this. I did see a warning the other day that the "phone app may seriously damage tablet" but I can't find the phone app to delete it. Any thoughts on how to stop it?

Comment: You probably taped on some phishing ads or you getting those. Phone app is usually dialer app and if you delete it phone will became unusable. However I see you aren't into android so the best solution is to flash stock firmware. And be carefull what you install and don't tap on ads that saying you have x viruses on phone or such things, use your brain.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a text that is shown in place of Advertisement. Don't take it seriously.Just delete unwanted applications from tablet

Answer (score 0):

This "Phone app may seriously damage your tablet" is just a scam.

If you are concerned that there might actually be malicious programs on the device, I recommend to download and run a scan using [MalwareBytes for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware&hl=en/) .